# Change for loop 'i' from within loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

Ok, so I'm moving from Java to Objective-C, heres my code (in C)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#import <tgmath.h>
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    const double seed = 5;
    int newSeed = seed;
    while (newSeed != 1){
        for (int i = sqrt(newSeed); i > 1; --i){
            if (isPrime((double) i)){
                if(newSeed/i == 1){
                    printf("%i", i);
                    newSeed = newSeed/i;
                }
            }
            if(i==1)
            {
                newSeed = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is , changing the first part of the for loop, the 'int i = sqrt(newSeed)'. So you can see i change the value of newSeed inside the for loop, but it doesn't change the starting for loop value.

I guess what I'm trying to do is branch of into a new for loop and break out of this one. ie break out of this for loop and redo it with the new

```
for (int i = sqrt(newSeed); i > 1; --i)
```

Comment: Just add `break;` after `newSeed = newSeed/i;` and move the `if(i==1)` statement to the outside of the loop.

Comment: are you trying to check for prime number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
    while (newSeed != 1){
        for (int i = sqrt(newSeed); i > 1; --i){
            if (isPrime((double) i)){
                if(newSeed/i == 1){
                    printf("%i", i);
                    newSeed = newSeed/i;
                    i = sqrt(newSeed); /* reassign the value of i */
                }
            }

            if(i==1)
            {
                newSeed = 1;
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = sqrt(newSeed); i > 1; --i){
        if (isPrime((double) i)){
            if(newSeed/i == 1){
                printf("%i", i);
                newSeed = newSeed/i;
            }
        }
```

if `newseed/i == 1` , then assigning `newseed= newseed/i` will always set `newseed=1`

also `for(int i= sqrt(newseed)...` means the `initial value for i` , you can't change `i` by changing `newseed` now, it was just used for initialisation. you may want to `change i` instead

for e.g `i = sqrt(newseed)` in your loop

may be what you mean to do is

```
for (int i = sqrt(newSeed); i > 1; --i){
            if (isPrime((double) i)){
                if(newSeed/i == 1){
                    printf("%i", i);

                }

                else{
                   newSeed = newSeed/i;
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. After the first assignment `i = sqrt(newSeed)` the loop doesn't visit that assignment any more, it only uses the last of the statement, `--i` in this case, to change the value of `i`.

If it did call the assignment each time in the loop, `i` would never change, would it!

The same is true in Java, by the way.